# Seventh of my system (5th of a riddle series)

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> This is the fifth of the series,
> are you becoming exhausted?
> I'm the seventh of my system,
> though not cold like that ice planet.
>
> I can come with your order,
> but you can order things without me.
> I'm sometimes like a bounty,
> which someone can put optionally.
>
> If I'm looked at from above,
> I'm read as an imagination.
> I can be inscribed in some shapes
> which can carry information.
>
> Who am I?

Comment: Wait... is it usual to release the fifth of a series before the fourth is completed?

Comment: Thats some nice rhyming there

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> The letter **U**?

---

*I'm the seventh of my system,

though not cold like that ice planet.*

> On a standard QWERTY keyboard, U is the **7th** key on its row, starting from the Q in "QWERTY."

*I can come with your order,

but you can order things without me.

I'm sometimes like a bounty,

which someone can put optionally.*

> When you order food, you can get *flav**ou**r* or *flav**o**r* from your food. The letter U doesn't have to come, as it is **"optional"** in some words when it comes to European vs American spelling.

*If I'm looked at from above,

I'm read as an imagination.*

> So I'm going to take this hint as meaning this: "looking in such a way from above that the subject is flipped vertically." And if we do that with "U", we get "∩", which most might call an arch. Hence, it being read as an **"imagination"**, or how it literally looks as an image, rather than by its actual name (intersection symbol).

*I can be inscribed in some shapes

which can carry information.*

> Obviously, the letter U can be inscribed on anything with writing. But if we take it further with Phylyp's observation about "shapes" possibly meaning street signs, we find that a common sign one might see on the road is one for a **U**-Turn.

Comment: Incorrect answer. Not too far away, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you are:

> **The colour red**

I'm the seventh of my system,
though not cold like that ice planet.

> Red is the 7th colour in a rainbow (VIBGYOR)
>  Not cold = hot; red is often used to indicate heat

I can come with your order,
but you can order things without me.

> Managers sometimes organize things with a RAG rating (red/amber/green)
>  However, that is not the only way of organizing things

I'm sometimes like a bounty,
which someone can put optionally.

> Red can be used to highlight or otherwise bring attention to notices (e.g. a [Red Notice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpol_notice) used by Interpol)

If I'm looked at from above,
I'm read as an imagination.

> Not sure of this, something to do with the letters r-e-d in the word *dream*?

I can be inscribed in some shapes
which can carry information.

> Certain types of traffic signs/road signs are filled in with red (e.g. a [no entry sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prohibitory_traffic_sign#/media/File:Australia_road_sign_R2-4-AS.svg))

Comment: Still moderately far away, but some explanations are correct.

Comment: "I can come with your order" = ketchup